# MSSQL query to select top 2 values

Tags: sql-server, query

I am not from a DBMS background and I couldn't find much help from reading some resources once.

I have a requirement like:  There are 5 interfaces with some execution time. My goal is to find the top 2 interfaces which took the most time.

```
  RowNum   Interface    TIME 
  1        Intf1        0 
  2        Intf2        3 
  3        intf5        1 
  4        Intf2        4 
  5        intf3        3 
  6        Intf2        2 
  7        intf3        5 
  8        intf3        2 
  9        inft4        2 
 10        Intf2        0 
 11        intf5        1
```

The max time taken is 5 which corresponds to Intf3 (so print all intf3  with their times) and the second max time taken is 4 corresponding to  Intf2(so print all intf2  with their times). So my expected output is:

```
RowNum  Interface   TIME
  7       intf3      5 
  5       intf3      3 
  8       intf3      2 
  4       Intf2      4 
  2       Intf2      3 
  6       Intf2      2 
  10      Intf2      0
```

I tried something like

```
select Row,Interface,Time 
from (select Row,Interface,Time from NAMES order by Time desc)
```

but it didn't seem to work as I was expecting.

Comment: Thanking is nice. Marking an answer is preferred and far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this ...
Here is one

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([RowNum] int, [Interface] varchar(5), [TIME] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([RowNum], [Interface], [TIME])
VALUES
    (1, 'Intf1', 0),
    (2, 'Intf2', 3),
    (3, 'intf5', 1),
    (4, 'Intf2', 4),
    (5, 'intf3', 3),
    (6, 'Intf2', 2),
    (7, 'intf3', 5),
    (8, 'intf3', 2),
    (9, 'inft4', 2),
    (10, 'Intf2', 0),
    (11, 'intf5', 1)

SELECT t.*
FROM table1 as t
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT Interface, Time , 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.Time dESC) as rn
     FROM Table1 as a
  ) AS P
  ON t.Interface = p.Interface
WHERE
  p.rn <=2
ORDER BY p.Time DESC,p.Interface,t.Time DESC
```

And output:

```
RowNum  Interface   TIME
7   intf3   5
5   intf3   3
8   intf3   2
4   Intf2   4
2   Intf2   3
6   Intf2   2
10  Intf2   0
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dbcc1bff1f13939bcee8f5854936d5f4)

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a `CTE` and `INNER JOIN`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tabl1
>     ([RowNum] int, [Interface] varchar(5), [TIME] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tabl1
>     ([RowNum], [Interface], [TIME])
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Intf1', 0),
>     (2, 'Intf2', 3),
>     (3, 'intf5', 1),
>     (4, 'Intf2', 4),
>     (5, 'intf3', 3),
>     (6, 'Intf2', 2),
>     (7, 'intf3', 5),
>     (8, 'intf3', 2),
>     (9, 'inft4', 2),
>     (10, 'Intf2', 0),
>     (11, 'intf5', 1)
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTEmaxtime ([Interface],[maxtime]) AS
> (SELECT TOP 2 [Interface],MAX([TIME]) FROM tabl1 
> GROUP BY [Interface]
> ORDER BY MAX([TIME]) DESC)
>
> SELECT
>   t1.[RowNum], t1.[Interface], t1.[TIME]
> FROM tabl1 t1 INNER JOIN CTEmaxtime ct ON ct.[Interface] = t1.[Interface]
> ORDER BY [maxtime] DESC ,[Interface], [TIME] DESC
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> RowNum | Interface | TIME
> -----: | :-------- | ---:
>      7 | intf3     |    5
>      5 | intf3     |    3
>      8 | intf3     |    2
>      4 | Intf2     |    4
>      2 | Intf2     |    3
>      6 | Intf2     |    2
>     10 | Intf2     |    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ff64c9154f3d8b1dd3b813707018f66)*